# How To Return The Right of An Either

Tags: scala

I have a value of this type:

```scala
List[Either[Error, Files]]
```

and I have a function which checks if there are any errors like this:

```scala
  private def process(result: List[Either[Error, Files]]): Either[Error, List[Files]] = {
    if(result.exists(p => p.isLeft)){
      Left(Error("some downloads failed"))
    }else{
      Right(
      Right(
        result.collect {
          case Right(value) => value
        }
      )

    }

  }
```

Is this the best way to return the List of files if there are no errors in result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `cats` libarary which has `sequence` extension method for doing such thing
https://gist.github.com/gbersac/14114f8bf8d0b1c6ea455aacdee0fcd8.

Comment: @Mojo Note that `sequence === traverse(id)` so if you got your **List[Either[Error, Files]]** from a `map` you can `data.traverse(f)` instead of `data.map(f).sequence`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses `partition`:

```
private def process(result: List[Either[Error, Files]]): Either[Error, List[Files]] =
  result.partition(_.isLeft) match {
    case (Left(error)::_, _) =>
      Left(error)
    case (_, r) =>
      Right(r.collect{ case Right(r) => r })
  }
```

This recursive version is more efficient but perhaps less clear:

```
private def process(result: List[Either[Error, Files]]): Either[Error, List[Files]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(rem: List[Either[Error, Files]], res: List[Files]): Either[Error, List[Files]] =
    rem match {
      case Left(error) :: _ =>
        Left(error)
      case Right(file) :: tail =>
        loop(tail, file +: res)
      case _ =>
        Right(res.reverse)
    }

  loop(result, Nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foldLeft` in this case, to collect either all errors or all files. I don't know how `Error` looks like, but suppose it is simple case class with message string inside:

```
case class Error(message: String) {
  def append(message: Error): Error = copy(message = message + s"; ${message.message}")
}

def process(result: List[Either[Error, Files]]): Either[Error, List[Files]] = {
  val init: Either[Error, List[Files]] = Right(Nil)
  result.foldLeft(init) {
    case (Left(allErrors), Left(currentError)) => Left(allErrors.append(currentError))
    case (Left(allErrors), Right(_)) => Left(allErrors)
    case (Right(_), Left(currentError)) => Left(currentError)
    case (Right(allFiles), Right(currentFile)) => Right(currentFile :: allFiles)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!